# How can I reach seq tag data via web scraping with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, fasta

I am a newbie to web scraping. I am trying to get FASTA file from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/193211599?report=fasta), but somehow I cannot. First of all the problem starting for me span tag, I tried some couple of suggestions but not working for me I am suspecting that maybe there is a privacy problem

The FASTA file in this class, but when I run this code, I just can see FASTA title:

```
url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/193211599?report=fasta"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
fasta_data = soup.find_all("div")
for link in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "seqrprt seqviewer"}):
    print link.text

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/193211599?report=fasta"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
fasta_data = soup.find_all("div")
for link in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "seqrprt seqviewer"}):
    print link.text

##When I try to reach directly via span, output is empty.
div = soup.find("div", {'id':'viewercontent1'})
spans = div.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    print span.string
```

Answer (score 1):

Every scraping job involves two phases:

1. Understand the page that you want to scrape. (How it works? content loaded from Ajax? redirections? POST? GET? iframes? antiscraping stuff?...)
2. Emulate the webpage using your favourite framework

Do not write a single line of code before to work on point 1. Google network inspector is your friend, use it!

Regarding your webpage, it seems that the report is loaded into a viewer getting data from this url:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=193211599&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=0&fmt_mask=0&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000

Use that url and you will get your report.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Can you please tell me how can you say that the viewer is fetching data from that particular url? Were you able to do it from google network inspector? If yes, how? Thanks.